# $update["message"]["text"] api telegram doesn't recognize message

Tags: php, api, bots, telegram

I'm writing a bot with PHP, which responds when I type a command.

But the bot works perfectly less when I write only a number 0. If I write any other number it works fine.

If I analyze $update["message"]["text"] into a log, [text] contains number 0. It's like I haven't written anything. Bot skips that message.

What is happening?

Comment: contains 0 or is only 0? if is only 0, try `(string)0`

Comment: Is only 0. (string)0 where?

Comment: as your text, you need to cast it to string

Comment: I'm trying manipulate 0 string but I don't get anything. When I write 0, telegram does nothing. I have to write another value for get a response. However if I write 00 it is valid.

Comment: because 0 is considered as false, could be a bug in api, what api is that? some link?

Comment: I've found a solution. 0 not be evaluated into switch, but before switch I can convert to string $update["message"]["text"] value. I convert 0 to "00" string, then I can convert to int or float, etc...